# Model form-data body request using Swagger 2.0 in yaml file

Tags: multipartform-data, openapi, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger 2.0 and I have an endpoint which is using form-data as the payload for the request, I am using the same form-data body request in several places and I don't want to write it again and again (duplicate it) and I don't know how to model it inside my yaml file (I do know how to model object when it is part of the request body as payload).

This is the form-data payload I am trying to model:

[image]

I looked at swagger's documentation: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/

and tried to do the same but I got errors as follow:

[image]

I don't want to duplicate the same values (if I do so it will work but the solution won't be elegant).

Answer (score 2):

In OpenAPI 2.0, you can only reuse the definitions of individual form fields/parameters. There's no way to reuse a set of fields/parameters.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'

parameters:
  name:
    in: formData
    name: name
    type: string
  upfile1:
    in: formData
    name: upfile1
    type: file
  ...

paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/name'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/upfile1'
        - ...

  /bar:
    post:
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/name'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/upfile1'
        - ...
```

To reuse the entire request body definition, you need OpenAPI 3.0. In OAS 3, request bodies can be defined in the global `components/requestBodies` section and referenced using `$ref`:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/statusMode'
      responses:
        ...

  /bar:
    post:
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/statusMode'
      responses:
        ...

components:
  requestBodies:
    statusMode:
      required: true
      content:
        multipart/form-data:
          schema:
            type: object
            # The properties correspond to individual form fields
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              upfile1:
                type: string
                format: binary
```